# Selenium test an iterface where misses id and title and other sensible information

Tags: selenium, junit, webdriver

I'm working for a client who wants me to do selenium/junit tests but the whole user interface doesn't show any id for the html code nor title for the page, just content like "Welcome in ...", how whould you do to check that one is on the home page or in the page for the login for example?

This is an example of the html:

```
<div class="site-body m-welcome" data-module="welcome">
<div class="inner">
  <h1 class="starred dark"><span>Welcome to ...</span></h1>

  <div class="choices">
    <div class="choice">
      <a href="http://www.alink/account/validate/driver" class="btn btn-primary">Become a xxxxx</a>
    </div>

    <span class="or"><span>Or</span></span>

    <form action="http://www.alink/welcome" method="post" class="choice" data-response-type="json">
              <input type="text" name="plate_number" id="car_plate_validation_plate_number" value="" maxlength="8" class="plate required numberplate" placeholder="Enter number plate">

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Become an yyyyy</button>

      <div class="invalid-message inline-modal" data-behavior="modal">
        <h1>Sorry - you are not eligible to join the company</h1>


        <p>See <a href="#">am I eligile?</a> for full eligibility critera.</p>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Show a sample HTML of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath to find almost all elements, I wouldn't use it often but in your case (where nothing has IDs) you'll probably need to use it very often:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath, "//*[text='Welcome in ...']");
```

That will get you the first element of any type that has the text within it of "Welcome in ..."

For checking if you are on a certain page, I guess you'll have to search for an element that is unique to that page and no other pages.

You'll need to show us some of the HTML if you want more specific examples.

Comment: I posted an example in an answer: :)

Comment: @Shilaghae So for example to get the 'am I eligile?' to click, you'd FindElement(By.Xpath, "//a[text='am I eligile?']");

Comment: You should read up about XPath more in order to be able to get the elements from the example HTML you posted.
http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp is always a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Example of html:

```
    <div class="site-body m-welcome" data-module="welcome">
    <div class="inner">
        <h1 class="starred dark"><span>Welcome to ...</span></h1>

        <div class="choices">
            <div class="choice">
                <a href="http://www.alink/account/validate/driver" class="btn btn-primary">Become a xxxxx</a>
            </div>

            <span class="or"><span>Or</span></span>

            <form action="http://www.alink/welcome" method="post" class="choice" data-response-type="json">
                                <input type="text" name="plate_number" id="car_plate_validation_plate_number" value="" maxlength="8" class="plate required numberplate" placeholder="Enter number plate">

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Become an yyyyy</button>

                <div class="invalid-message inline-modal" data-behavior="modal">
                    <h1>Sorry - you are not eligible to join the company</h1>


                    <p>See <a href="#">am I eligile?</a> for full eligibility critera.</p>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you tell us which is the unique tag in the above html helps you differentiate if the page is a login or a home page. Then I can help you find if the page is a login page or not using selenium.

Comment: it is the problem, I have just this kind of code, it wasn't write by me but I have to test it, I can't change this html. :(

Comment: I can understand that you can change the HTML, but at least the text such as "welcome in.." etc must be different in the home page and the login page.